# A command to run the command that was executed right before the most recent one?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In bash, to run the most recent command you used, you can either press the up arrow key on your keyboard and press `Enter` or type `!!` and press `Enter`. But, is there a command that you can use to run the command that was executed right before the most recent one? For example:

```
$ pwd
/home/john
$ ls
bin      Documents  Music   Pictures  Templates
Desktop  Downloads  output  Public    Videos
```

Typing in `!!` and pressing `Enter` will run the `ls` command again. But, is there something similar to the `!!` command that will let you run the `pwd` command in the same manner? If there is one, give some more details as to how it works.

Comment: There is a *lot* more to history expansion than just `!!`; check the man page for the full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `!n`, where `n` is line number in your history. To get the second to last command you can then use `!-2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!-2` like is mentioned here. Along with the up arrow, you can cycle back through your history with ctrl-p as well, forward with ctrl-n.  You can also use ctrl-r and do reverse search for a command you've already entered.

Comment: Keep in mind the exact key bindings for navigating history may vary from person to person (although if they do, that person probably knows what they are doing already), but history expansion is fixed by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember the beginning characters of last executed commands,
you can execute it by specify the beginning characters of the command with !

from your question, to execute ls again, use the **!l**,
and **!p** or **!pw** to execute pwd command.but it only execute the last executed one.